# why does ssdt offests in windows x64 SSDT are shifted by 4 bits?

Tags: windows, kernel

I am learning on the SSDT and I wondered why in x64 windows when extracting the offset we divide it in 16 (shift 4)?
Why does it needed? what does this optimization give? why don't we just add it to the base address?
Thanks Idan.